# How do I get the (X,Y) coordinate of my cursor on a worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to create a graph, with the top left of it being on my cursor position. Is that possible? Can the (X,Y) of my mouse be converted into a range format?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hm, it's not exactly built in AFAIK, but I found [this page](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19124) which gives a suggestion that worked for me:

In a module, put this at the top:

```
Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare Function ScreenToClient Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
    Private Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type
```

Then, for the subroutines to get the mouseX and mouseY, put this somewhere below:

```
Function MouseX(Optional ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
' Get mouse X coordinates in pixels
'
' If a window handle is passed, the result is relative to the client area
' of that window, otherwise the result is relative to the screen
    Dim lpPoint As POINTAPI
    Application.Volatile(false)
    GetCursorPos lpPoint
    If hWnd Then ScreenToClient hWnd, lpPoint
    MouseX = lpPoint.X
End Function
```

and

```
Function MouseY(Optional ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
' Get mouse Y coordinates in pixels
'
' If a window handle is passed, the result is relative to the client area
' of that window, otherwise the result is relative to the screen

    Dim lpPoint As POINTAPI
    Application.Volatile(false)
    GetCursorPos lpPoint
    If hWnd Then ScreenToClient hWnd, lpPoint
    MouseY = lpPoint.Y
End Function
```

Then, in Excel, if you simply enter into a cell `=mouseX()` it'll return the mouseX position when you hit `ENTER`.  Same with `=mouseY()`.

Trying it out, I did:

```
Sub chart_Test()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Top = MouseY()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Left = MouseX()

End Sub
```

and got it to work.

edit: Note, I'm not as good with charts as other things in VBA, so as you create charts, you'll need to edit the `.Shapes("Chart 1").` part to whatever chart name/number you're on.  Or iterate through them.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the mouse x y but you could get the range on worksheet selection change.  Put the chart at that location.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Chart.Left = Target.column
    Chant.Top  = Target.row
End Sub
```

Comment: While it's not what OP asked for, I think this would be your better bet.  The mouseX/mouseY may work, but if you can do it, I would define the chart location by a cell's location, instead of mouseX/mouseY because your mouse has to be exactly where you want it, when you run the macro (in the code I posted anyways).  Nice thinking @matthewD

Comment: Remember that using Windows library functions makes your code useless if it needs to run on Excel for Mac. A pure VBA solution is likely going to be supported on both platforms.